# model class not found in a view-composer

Tags: view, model, laravel-4, composer-php

I would call a model to retrieve information from the database, using a view-composer, but I get the error : "Class 'App\Composers\Region' not found"

My file "filtersComposer" is in the "composers" folder, which is automatically loaded with the composer.json

In my method "compose($view)" I call my model like this:

```
$regions = Region::all()->lists('region_intitule', 'region_id');
```

and then, for example I send to my view

```
$view->with('localities', $regions)
```

But it seems that the Region class is not accessible.
In addition, Region class is not in the "composers" folder but in my "models" folder.

Please, tell me how to retrieve information from the database in my class filtersComposer?

thank you for the help

Composer service provider  in "app/composers" :

```
namespace App\Composers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

  public function register()
  {
    $this->app->view->composer('includes/filtersBar/verticalFilter', 'App\Composers\FiltersComposer');
  }

}
```

FiltersComposer, also in "app/composers"

```
namespace App\Composers;

Class FiltersComposer {

    public function compose($view)
    {
        $regions = Region::all()->lists('region_intitule', 'region_id');

        $view->with('localities', $regions);
    }
}
```

Moreover, my composers dont work without the prefix "App\" in the namespace... But it's not a problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your FiltersComposer is in `App\Composers` namespace. PHP thinks your Region is App\Composers\Region.

I believe you created your Region model the typical way, which is in the global namespace. So try this instead:

```
$regions = \Region::all()->lists('region_intitule', 'region_id');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer 
Now it works, and I also use this namespace for Cache:: ... 

Thank you!

Comment: Had the same problem, this was the perfect answer by adding \ infront of the model name